# How do I output top readers from MySql table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to output top readers from a library management system to see who read most this year, but I am stuck with the query building.

I have 3 tables,

books

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name of the book1 |
| 2 | name of the book2 |
| 3 | name of the book3 |
| 4 | name of the book4 |

book_issues

| id | student_id | book_id | issue_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2022-05-09 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 2022-05-01 |
| 3 | 3 | 5 | 2022-05-06 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2022-05-08 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 2022-05-03 |

and student

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name of the student1 |
| 2 | name of the student2 |
| 3 | name of the student3 |
| 4 | name of the student4 |

this is my controller

```
public function topmonth_wise()
{
    return view('report.topmonthWise', ['books' => '']);
}

public function generate_topmonth_wise_report(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate(['month' => "required|date"]);
    return view('report.topmonthWise', [
        'books' => book_issue::where('issue_date', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->month . '%')
               // ->select(student::raw('count(book_id) as top'))
                //->groupBy('top')
                //->orderBy('top', 'DESC')
                ->limit(10)
                //->latest()
                ->get(),
    ]);
}
```

and this is my view:

```
<table class="content-table">
    <thead>
        <th>Nr. Crt</th>
        <th>Nume elev</th>
        <th>Total carti citite</th>
        
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @forelse ($books as $book)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $book->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $book->student->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $book->count() }}</td>
                
            </tr>
        @empty
            <tr>
                <td colspan="10">Nu s-au găsit înregistrări!</td>
            </tr>
        @endforelse
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this is my model:

```
public function student(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(student::class, 'student_id', 'id');
}

/**
 * Get the book that owns the book_issue
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function book(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(book::class, 'book_id', 'id');
}
```

I want to show the top readers of the month in my view but I get an error if I use the code from the controller
all I want is the view to show a table like this:

| id | student name | total books read |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | student name 2 | 3 |
| 2 | student name 1 | 1 |
| 3 | student name 3 | 1 |

if you want to see other files I'll give you just ask
who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by `student_id`, and then you need to count the total items inside that particular id.

```
//here we loaded students as well as we need to know the name
//and then group by `student_id`

$book_issues = book_issue::with('student')
->where('issue_date', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->month . '%')
->get()
->groupBy('student_id');

$row = 1;
@foreach($book_issues as $k => $v)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$row}}</td>
        <td>{{$v->first()->student->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$$v->count()}}</td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        $row++;
    ?>
@endforeach
```

Comment: i have a where condition by mont selected from view, you can see it in controller, the code you post where i have to put only in the view blade?

Comment: @coZmoXimo I have added your where condition as well.

Comment: its working, now remain to orderBy count, i tried to put orederby after Group but i get an error, groupBy doesen't exist....

Comment: I manged to finalize the code, thanks Saroj Shrestha after groupby i added ->sortDesc();